# Not able to ping VM and/or mount NFS after changing IP via POSTROUTING

Tags: ip, nat, ping, virtual-ip

Imagine the following setup.

I have a machine A which exports a network share and is reachable under, say 1.1.1.1.

A second B machine with an IP, say 2.2.2.2, is mounting that share, everything's fine.

Now I'm trying to setup some kind of blue/green development. 
The machine B starts with the IP 2.2.2.2. When I assign some kind of a new Virtual IP (like ElasticIP from AWS, but in my case Floating IP from Hetzner Cloud), I create a new POSTROUTING entry in the iptables with

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source $FIP
```

which results correctly in

```
10      20  1415 SNAT       all  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            to:x.x.x.x
```

That means, the machine B now communicates with the new IP address.

Here comes the pain:
I no longer can mount and/or ping the machine A with the IP 1.1.1.1 from machine B.
Machine A is 'pingable' from anywhere but from Machine B with the new IP address.

How come? Any ideas?